# How do I include more objective functions in my TMB .cpp file?

Tags: c++, r, tmb

The TMB objective functions are seemingly defined in one function block that is saved to a `<name>.cpp` file. Then, after compiling the file, each objective function is accessed by loading with the command `dyn.load(dynlib(<name>))`.

Is it possible to store more than one objective function in each `.cpp` file? For example, the following two objective functions are very similar to each other, but at the moment need to be saved to different files:

```cpp
// TMB Tutorial but with fixed variance
#include <TMB.hpp>                                // Links in the TMB libraries

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
    DATA_VECTOR(x);                                 // Data vector transmitted from R
    PARAMETER(mu);                                  // Parameter value transmitted from R
    Type sigma = 1.0;

    Type f;                                         // Declare the "objective function" (neg. log. likelihood)
    f = -sum(dnorm(x,mu,sigma,true));               // Use R-style call to normal density

    return f;
}
```

and

```cpp
// TMB Tutorial
#include <TMB.hpp>                                // Links in the TMB libraries

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
    DATA_VECTOR(x);                                 // Data vector transmitted from R
    PARAMETER(mu);                                  // Parameter value transmitted from R
    PARAMETER(sigma);                               //                 

    Type f;                                         // Declare the "objective function" (neg. log. likelihood)
    f = -sum(dnorm(x,mu,sigma,true));               // Use R-style call to normal density

    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "map" argument to `MakeADFun()` allows you to fix parameters at specific values.

In this example, we only need to compile/load the latter template. First, we'll write the template to a file, compile, and load the resulting DLL.

```
library(TMB)

file_conn <- file('test.cpp')

writeLines("
#include <TMB.hpp>                                

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
    DATA_VECTOR(x);                                 
    PARAMETER(mu);                                  
    PARAMETER(sigma);                               

    Type f;                                         
    f = -sum(dnorm(x,mu,sigma,true));               

    return f;
}
", file_conn)
close(file_conn)

compile('test.cpp')
dyn.load(dynlib('test'))
```

We can use the same DLL to fit models with and without a varying sigma.

```
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1) 

f1 <- MakeADFun(data = list(x = x),
               parameters = list(mu = 0, sigma = 1),
               DLL = 'test')

f2 <- MakeADFun(data = list(x = x),
                parameters = list(mu = 0, sigma = 1),
                DLL = 'test',
                map = list(sigma = factor(NA)))

opt1 <- do.call('optim', f1)
opt2 <- do.call('optim', f2)
```

When using "map", the specified parameter(s) (sigma in this case) is fixed at the value given in "parameters".

Post-optimization, we do a sanity check -- the mus ought to be nearly identical.

```
> opt1$par
        mu      sigma 
0.08300554 1.07926521 
> opt2$par
        mu 
0.08300712
```

Turning random effects on and off is a little more difficult. An example of that is given [here](https://github.com/kaskr/adcomp/issues/154), where you can use `CppAD::Variable()` to check whether to decrement the negative log-likelihood or not.

For unalike objective functions (not subsets of one another), you could pass a `DATA_INTEGER` or `DATA_STRING` into the template, e.g. like they did in glmmTMB [here](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/blob/master/glmmTMB/src/glmmTMB.cpp#L576), and pick the objective function depending on the value of that `DATA_*`.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to make clear on what @alexforrence meant by

> For unalike objective functions (not subsets of one another), you could pass a DATA_INTEGER or DATA_STRING into the template, e.g. like they did in glmmTMB here, and pick the objective function depending on the value of that DATA_*

It turns out there is a [code snippet](https://github.com/kaskr/adcomp/issues/233#issuecomment-306032192) on the TMB github that covers this scenario, which I duplicate here:

```
#include <TMB.hpp>

template<class Type>
Type objective_function<Type>::operator() ()
{
  DATA_STRING(model_type);
  if (model_type == "model1") {
    #include "model1.h"
  } else
  if (model_type == "model2") {
    #include "model2.h"
  } else {
    error ("Unknown model type")
  }
  return 0;
}
```

That is, pass in a string telling the objective function which model to choose, and then include the text for that function stored in a separate `.h` file.